# How to set permission on Volume mount point AWS CDK

Tags: aws-cdk

In my CDK app I have an ElasticSearch docker that starts on an EC2 instance and on start up it cannot write to the host path's Volume mount point directory which I set to /mnt/data/elasticsearch/ so the container stops,
The reason is the permissions on the directory when the instance is starts is 755. When I SSH into the instance and change it to 777 the container starts up and continues on without issue.

This is how I create the volume and mount point

```
 import software.amazon.awscdk.services.ecs.Volume
 
 // These two lines have no effect 
 auto_scaling_group.addUserData("sudo mkdir -m 777  /usr/share/elasticsearch/data);
 auto_scaling_group.addUserData("sudo chmod -R 777  /usr/share/elasticsearch/data);` 

 Volume hostVolume =  Volume.builder().name("elasticsearch").host(Host.builder()
                         .sourcePath(/mnt/data/elasticsearch).build()).build();
 
MountPoint elasticSrvrMntPt = MountPoint.builder().readOnly(false).sourceVolume(hostVolume.getName())
                .containerPath("/usr/share/elasticsearch/data").build();

ElasticDef.addMountPoints(elasticSrvrMntPt);
```

I cannot find in the API how to either give permission to that container or change the permission on the folder

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because I was using a bind mounts to mount at container, By default, the volume permissions are set to 0755 and the owner as root. The permissions would need be changed in the Elastic Dockerfile. Instead I used Volume to mount the host dir
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/bind-mounts.html